# Reference Excel files getting filename from a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get values from different excel files (say, File-AAA.xlsx, File-ABC.xlsx, etc). ¿How can I reference said files without inputting manually the "ABC" part of the filename, but **getting it from the current sheet instead**?

[image: Excel question example]

In the example, from our current sheet we want to get the values of A1 and A2, from the *File-ABC.xlsx* file, and sum them.

For instance, in B2, instead of writing:

```
    =SUM('\\server\path\[File-ABC.xlsx]Data'!A1:A2)
```

I would like to be able to write it as

```
    =SUM('\\server\path\[File-*REFERENCE TO CELL*.xlsx]Data'!A1:A2)
```

Where *REFERENCE TO CELL* is the **sought text string** that references the cell that contains "ABC" (A2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **indirect** function for this.
Something like this -

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'\\server\path\[File-"&A2&".xlsx]Data'!A1"&":"&"A2"))
```

**Edit-1 :**
You can use the same syntax to refer to the local directory that you want, just replace **\server\path[File-** with the path of the new directory. You can copy the path from your file explorer after browsing to the concerned folder.

Eg. Taking the path from your comment *(after correction)*:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'C:\Users\PeteThePanda\Spreadsheets[File-"&A3&".xlsx]Data'!A1"&‌​":"&"A2"))
```

Comment: fwiw, the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) cannot be used to refernce a closed external workbook.

Comment: This worked! But I can't figure out the syntax if it's a local file, say, located in the C drive. What if the file was located in the
" C:\Users\PeteThePanda\Spreadsheets\ " directory? Could you provide an example for that other case?

Comment: I provided an example in the answer edit. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you!. I got it! However, I had to tweak a bit the example you provided. The actual working example is **=SUM(INDIRECT("'C:\Users\PeteThePanda\Spreadsheets\[File-"&A3&".xlsx]Data'!A1"&":"&"A2"))**. Please make the edit so I can mark as fully answered.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward way to do this is set up a conditional statement outside the sum, e.g. if the value of A2 in the current workbook is ABC, then go to this path and bring in the sum.

e.g.

`=if(A2="ABC",sum('\\server\path\[File-ABC.xlsx]Data'!A1:A2),if(A2="AAA", sum('\\server\path\[File-AAA.xlsx]Data'!A1:A2),"No File"))`

Note, you can add additional nested IFs if there are more files. Just start a new if where I wrote "No File".